# CSS positioning seems not to be loaded on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, css-position

I'm creating a responsive website but it seems to me the CSS is not loading the positioning of divs on iOS.

How it looked like without JS on iPhone 5s:
[image: Iphone 5s]

So, what I tryed is to find a way around the CSS by javascript and jquery allthough this seems to work, it still doesn't so it's job properly. And the lenth of my code would be enormous if i would declare evere iOS device in new js code like this:

```
 /* Begin iPhone 5 portrait */

  if (blockwidth == 67.375) {
    $('input[type="date"]').css("width", "53px");
    $('input[type="time"]').css("width", "53px");
    $('input[type="date"]').css("height", "42px");
    $('input[type="time"]').css("height", "42px");
    $('input[type="text"]').css("height", "42px");
    $('input[type="text"]').css("width", "93%");
    $('input[type="button"]').css("height", "50px");
    $('#nav_top').css("height", "170px");
    $('#nav_logout').css("marginTop", "5px");
    $('#nav_account').css("marginTop", "5px");
  } else {}

  /* Einde iPhone 5 portrait */
```

The total CSS (also in JSFiddle):

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


/* CSS RESET */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
width : 5px;
opacity: 0.2;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar:hover {
width : 5px;
opacity: 0.6;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
background-color: black;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
background-color : #288328;
}
::-moz-scrollbar {
width : 5px;
-moz-opacity:0.2;
}
::-moz-scrollbar:hover {
width : 5px;
-moz-opacity:0.6;
}
::-moz-scrollbar-track {
background-color : black;
}
::-moz-scrollbar-thumb {
background-color : #288328;
}

/*  Kuler: 

    Olijfgroen:     #95c11f
    Donkergroen:    #288328
    Limoengroen:    #e3f4ae
    Oranje:         #f39200
    Wit:            white
    Zwart:          black
    Grijs:          lightgrey

*/

/* OWN CODE CSS */
html {
   margin: 0px;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}

body {
   margin: 0px;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}

.loader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url('../img/page-loader.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat #95c11f;
    background-size: 75px 75px;
}

/* BEGIN NAVIGATIE */

aside{
    margin: 0px;
    height:100%;
    width: 25%;
    background-color:#95c11f;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 0px 15px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    5px 0px 15px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         5px 0px 15px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    }

#aside_logout{
    margin-left:20px;
    background-color:#288328;
    color:white;
    display:inline-block;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 25px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 10px 25px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
    box-shadow:         0px 10px 25px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    }

#aside_account{
    margin-left:10px;   
    background-color:#f39200;
    color:white;
    display:inline-block;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 25px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 10px 25px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
    box-shadow:         0px 10px 25px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    }

#aside_bottom{
        width:100%;
        height:50px;
        position:fixed;
        bottom:-10px;
        }

#aside_bottom a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    }   

.left{
    float:left;
    }

header{
        display:none;
        width:100%;
        height:70px;
        background-color:#95c11f;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
        -moz-box-shadow:    0px 5px 15px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
        box-shadow:         0px 5px 15px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
        }

#menu_placement{
    height:300px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:120px;
    margin-right:20px;
    }

nav{
    display:none;
    position: fixed;
    top:60px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    z-index:500;
    }

.men_button{
    height:50px;
    width:auto;
    display:block;
    text-align:left;
    color: #288328;
    font-weight:400;
    margin:0 auto;
    color:white;
    float:left;
    }

.men_button a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    }

.icon_menubutton{
    width:40px;
    margin-top:5px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    }

.menu_content{
    display:inline-block;
    height:30px;
    width:100px;
    margin-left:10px;
    line-height:50px;
    float:left;
    }

form{
    height: 110px;
    }

input{
    display:block;
    height:50px;
    border:none;
    border-radius:5px;
    text-align:center;
    }

input[type='text']{
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    margin-top:10px;
    background-image:url(../img/icon_search.png);
    background-position:right;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }

input[type='date']{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    background-image:url(../img/icon_date.png);
    background-position:right;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }

input[type='time']{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    background-image:url(../img/icon_time.png);
    background-position:right;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }

input[type='text'], input[type='date'], input[type='time']  {
    background-color:#e3f4ae;
    color:#95c11f;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0px 2px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
    box-shadow:         inset 0px 2px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    }

input[type='button']{
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 2px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
    box-shadow:         0px 2px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
    background-color: #288328;
    color:white;
    font-size:18px;
    }

#aside_form{margin-top:20px;}

#nav_form{
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    }


#small_logo{
    width:100px;
    height:auto;
    margin-left:20px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    float:left;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.50);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 2px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.50);
    box-shadow:         0px 2px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.50);
    }

header #small_logo{
    width:60px;
    position: fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:500;
    height:auto;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    float:left;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.50);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 2px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.50);
    box-shadow:         0px 2px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.50);
    }

#menu_opener{
    width:40px;
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-right:15px;
    height:auto;
    float:right;
    }       

#logo{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    }

header #logo{
    width:auto;
    height:40px;
    margin-top:12.5px;
    margin-left:85px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    }

@media screen and (max-width: 360px), screen and (max-device-width: 360px) {
header #logo{
    width:auto;
    height:35px;
    margin-top:15px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    }

.menu_content{
    height:50px;
    width:auto;
    margin-left:10px;
    line-height:50px;
    font-size:11px;
    }

}

/* EIND NAVIGATIE */    

/* BEGIN BLOCKSTYLE */

#blocks{
    margin: 0px;
    height:100%;
    width: 75%;
    background-color:black;
    float:right;
    z-index:500;
    }

.block{
    margin: 0px;
    width:calc(100% / 3);
    background-image: url(../img/bg.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center center;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    font-weight:normal;
    }

.blockfooter{
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    margin-bottom:25px;
    }

.tagblock{
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    }

.tagline{
    height:50px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    padding-left:15px;
    float:left;
    line-height:50px;
    font-size:19px;
    }
.amounttag{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:#95c11f;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:right;
    color:white;
    line-height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:30px;
    }

.pricetag{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:#288328;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:right;
    color:white;
    line-height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    }

.allergictag{
    height:50px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:left;
    }

.icontag{
    width:170px;
    height:30px;
    padding:10px;

    text-align: justify;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    }

.icons{
    width:30px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    }

.stretch {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0
}

.datetag{
    height:25px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:#f39200;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:right;
    color:white;
    line-height:35px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:14px;
    }
.timetag{
    height:25px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:#f39200;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:right;
    color:white;
    line-height:15px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    }

/* EIND BLOCKSTYLE */

/*  Kuler: 

    Olijfgroen:     #95c11f
    Donkergroen:    #288328
    Limoengroen:    #e3f4ae
    Oranje:         #f39200
    Wit:            white
    Zwart:          black
    Grijs:          lightgrey

*/

@media screen and (max-width: 1220px), screen and (max-device-width: 1220px) {

/* BEGIN NAVIGATIE */

    aside{
    margin: 0px;
    height:100%;
    width: 25%;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    }

header, nav{display:none;}

/* EIND NAVIGATIE */    

/* BEGIN BLOCKSTYLE */

#blocks{
    margin: 0px;
    height:100%;
    width: 75%;
    background-color:black;
    float:right;
    }

.block{
    margin: 0px;
    width:50%;
    background-image: url(../img/bg.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center center;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    font-weight:normal;
    }

/* EIND BLOCKSTYLE */

}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px), screen and (max-device-width: 900px) {

/* BEGIN NAVIGATIE */

    aside{
        display:none;
    }

    header{
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:0;
    }

    #nav_top{
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
        background-color:#95c11f;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 20px 25px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
        -moz-box-shadow:    0px 20px 25px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
        box-shadow:         0px 20px 25px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
        }



    #menu_nav_placement{
        margin-left:20px;
        height:50px;
        margin-bottom:5px;
        }   

    .men_button{
    height:50px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:left;
    font-weight:400;
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    float:inherit;
    }

.icon_menubutton{
    width:40px;
    margin-top:5px;
    float:left;
    }

.menu_content{
    height:50px;
    width:auto;
    margin-left:10px;
    line-height:50px;
    }

.left{
    float:left;
    }
.right{
    float:right;
    }

#nav_logout{
    margin-left:20px;
    background-color:#288328;
    color:white;
    display:inline-block;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 25px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5), inset 0px 23px 15px -13px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 10px 25px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5), inset 0px 23px 15px -13px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
    box-shadow:         0px 10px 25px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5), inset 0px 23px 15px -13px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    }

#nav_account{
    margin-right:20px;  
    background-color:#f39200;
    color:white;
    display:inline-block;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 25px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5), inset 0px 23px 15px -13px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 10px 25px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5), inset 0px 23px 15px -13px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
    box-shadow:         0px 10px 25px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5), inset 0px 23px 15px -13px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    }

#nav_bottom{
        width:100%;
        height:50px;
        margin-top:-5px;
        }

#nav_bottom a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    }



/* EIND NAVIGATIE */

/* BEGIN BLOCKSTYLE */

    #blocks{
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    float:right;
    margin-top:70px;
    }

    .block{
    margin: 0px;
    height:200px;
    width:50%;
    background-color:rgba(255,0,4,1.00);
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    }

/* EIND BLOCKSTYLE */

}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px), screen and (max-device-width: 600px) {

    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
width : 0px;
opacity: 0.2;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar:hover {
width : 0px;
opacity: 0.6;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
background-color: black;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
background-color : #288328;
}
::-moz-scrollbar {
width : 0px;
-moz-opacity:0.2;
}
::-moz-scrollbar:hover {
width : 0px;
-moz-opacity:0.6;
}
::-moz-scrollbar-track {
background-color : black;
}
::-moz-scrollbar-thumb {
background-color : #288328;
}

/* BEGIN NAVIGATIE */

    aside{
        display:none;
    }

    header{
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    }

input[type='date']{
    background-position:center;
    }

input[type='time']{
    background-position:center;
    }

/* EIND NAVIGATIE */

/* BEGIN BLOCKSTYLE */

    #blocks{
    margin-top:70px;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    float:right;
    }

    .block{
    margin: 0px;
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:black;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    }

/* EIND BLOCKSTYLE */

}
```

Here's the total code sample:
https://jsfiddle.net/LLgsqyfc/

The normal @media query and the @ media query for aspect ratio's of devices didn't work either.

Comment: You dont need to 'find a way around CSS', if the media queries do not work then you arent using them correctly. Check out a few tutorials (there are a few million of them). Beyond that, delete your current post and post your CSS and lets work that out.

Comment: And did you set a position, other than the default `static` ?

Comment: I've posted the css now.